# Setting bounds on a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that contains two subviews, each of which is exactly the size of the device's screen.  I set the size of the child views in my `AppDelegate`:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[self window] bounds];
[[myViewController1 view] setFrame:screenRect];
screenRect.origin.x = screenRect.size.width;
[[myViewController2 view] setFrame:screenRect];
```

I then add these views to a `UIScrollView` and set the UIScrollView's `contentSize` to be twice the width of the screen:

```
CGRect containerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width * 2, screenRect.size.height);
UIScrollView *sv = (UIScrollView *)[myRootViewController view];
[sv addSubview:[myViewController1 view]];
[sv addSubview:[myViewController2 view]];
[sv setFrame:[[self window] bounds]];
[sv setContentSize:containerRect.size];
```

When the app runs, I see the views side by side, as expected.  However, both view are much wider than the screen width.  In addition, the `UIScrollView` doesn't restrict vertical scrolling, which I would expect as its height is equal to the screen height.

How can I make the UIScrollView restrict vertical scrolling and force its children to render in the appropriate-sized frame?

Comment: You did not set the scrollviews frame just it's content size

Comment: @Eyeball: I do actually set the frame earlier, I just forgot to add that here.  I've edited my question, thanks.

Comment: Is the rootviewcontroller infact a scrollview? Is it created programmatically or via IB?

Comment: What method contains the code in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you logged your [[self window] bounds]? It's possible it includes the statusbar, which would make your content views 20pts too high (thus enabling vertical scrolling). Perhaps:

```
CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
myViewController1.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(screenFrame), CGRectGetHeight(screenFrame));
myViewController2.view.frame = CGRectOffset(myViewController1.view.frame, CGRectGetWidth(screenFrame), 0.0);
```

And then:

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(screenFrame), CGRectGetHeight(screenFrame));
UIScrollView *sv = (UIScrollView *)myRootViewController.view;
[sv addSubview:myViewController1.view];
[sv addSubview:myViewController2.view];
[sv setContentSize:contentRect.size];
```